# How to get category name in cms page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I created two pages first one is "London" and other one is "Oxford".
and i also created two categories with these same name."Oxford" 
category have identifier  (ID:2) and "London" have identifier (ID:4).
i putted this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

code in oxford's content section.and

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

code in London's content section.

**I want to get current category id on list.phtml**.

i tried some code like

```
<?php echo $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();?>
```

but it always showing category id=2 whether i am on oxford page or London page

Comment: post more code i.e. print_r()

Comment: you are just passing category id as an argument.As you have not set current category id with a new value hence you will get 2 as output.

Comment: @SatishMantri:can you please explain briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the category_id is passed as a variable, so you can use following code in list.phtml file for getting the  current category id.

```
$current_catid=$this->getCategoryId(); // this will give your current category id
```

We can pass variable while instantiating any block class, as each block class is a derived class of Varien_Object and In the Varien_Object class constructor , every variable that is passed in the constructor, is set as the class property. For further reference please look at lib/Varian/Varian_Object class.